# Insert when not matched using merge

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert a record into a table using MERGE.
If EmployeeCode doesn't exist in the table it should insert the a new record.

My Code is like this

```
DECLARE     @EmployeeCode           BIGINT = 1234,
            @FirstName              VARCHAR(250) = 'FirstName',
            @MiddleName             VARCHAR(250) = 'LastName',
            @LastName               VARCHAR(250) = 'LastName',
            @Nationality            VARCHAR(250) = 'Nationality',
            @BloodGroup             VARCHAR(4) = 'A+',
            @Gender                 VARCHAR(7)  = 'Male'

MERGE dbo.tbTableName AS tb1
USING ( SELECT  tbTableName.EmployeeCode
        FROM    dbo.tbTableName tbTableName
        WHERE   tbTableName.EmployeeCode    =   @EmployeeCode) AS tb2 (EmployeeCode)
ON  (tb1.EmployeeCode = tb2.EmployeeCode)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (    EmployeeCode, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName,Nationality, BloodGroup, Gender )
    VALUES (    @EmployeeCode, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @Nationality, @BloodGroup, @Gender );
```

The issue I am having is that even when the EmployeeCode doesn't match any records in the table its not inserting.

Comment: MySQL or MSSQL?.

Comment: @wchiquito MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

I have used an alternative way to solve the problem using by using IF statement like this:

```
DECLARE     @EmployeeCode           BIGINT = 1234,
            @FirstName              VARCHAR(250) = 'FirstName',
            @MiddleName             VARCHAR(250) = 'LastName',
            @LastName               VARCHAR(250) = 'LastName',
            @Nationality            VARCHAR(250) = 'Nationality',
            @BloodGroup             VARCHAR(4)   = 'A+',
            @Gender                 VARCHAR(7)   = 'Male'

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  tbTableName.EmployeeCode
                FROM    dbo.tbTableName tbTableName
                WHERE   tbTableName.EmployeeCode    =   @EmployeeCode)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.tbTableName (EmployeeCode, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName,Nationality, BloodGroup, Gender )
VALUES (@EmployeeCode, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @Nationality, @BloodGroup, @Gender )

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Now is the time to go read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) and **study** the first example. That example shows the conversion from a tradition if/else update/insert code block to a single merge statement. Notice how the table source is defined in the example. You are selecting a row from a table (which you know does not exist) - so there are effectively no rows to be used for either insert or update. That is why nothing is inserted. The source of your merge information should be your set of variables just like the documentation example. An abbreviated version:

```
set nocount on;
DECLARE     @EmployeeCode           BIGINT = 1234,
        @FirstName              VARCHAR(250) = 'FirstName',
        @MiddleName             VARCHAR(250) = 'LastName',
        @LastName               VARCHAR(250) = 'LastName',
        @Nationality            VARCHAR(250) = 'Nationality',
        @BloodGroup             VARCHAR(4) = 'A+',
        @Gender                 VARCHAR(7)  = 'Male';

declare @tbl table (EmployeeCode bigint, FirstName varchar(250)); 
--insert @tbl(EmployeeCode, FirstName) values (1234, 'zork');

MERGE @tbl AS tb1
USING ( SELECT  @EmployeeCode, @FirstName) as src(EmployeeCode, FirstName)
ON  (tb1.EmployeeCode = src.EmployeeCode)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (    EmployeeCode, FirstName )
VALUES (    @EmployeeCode, @FirstName );

select @@ROWCOUNT, * from @tbl;
```